# htaccess rule for multilingual site (working on temporary site)

Tags: .htaccess

That is my standard RewriteRule I'm using everywhere

```
RewriteRule (.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.htm$ index.php?v=$1&page=$2&folder=$3
```

This convert my link: `mywebsite.com/index.php?v=parm1&page=parm2&folder=parm3` to `mywebsite.com/parm1-parm2-parm3.htm`

Now I need to add language support (&lang=pl) so the link will look like this: `mywebsite.com/pl/parm1-parm2-parm3.htm`

This will have to also work on temporary address: `mywebsite.com/~website/`

I know how to do just language (see below) without other parameters but don't know how to join those 2 rules together:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|pl)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

EDIT:

`mywebsite.com/` this should open home page in main `en` language

`mywebsite.com/parm1-parm2-parm3.htm`  this should open any page in main `en` language

`mywebsite.com/pl/` this should open home page in secondary language

`mywebsite.com/pl/parm1-parm2-parm3.htm`  this should open any page in secondary language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't just merge Regex ?

```
RewriteRule ^(en|pl)/(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.htm$ index.php?v=$2&page=$3&folder=$4&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en|pl)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. How to now change language on current page?  I have flags on top with link `?lang=en`. When I will change link to `/en/` than that will redirect to `/en/index.php`

Comment: There is a problem. I can open `mywebsite.com/en/parm1-parm2-parm3.htm` but if I would like to open main page `mywebsite.com/en/` than I'm getting error webiste not found

Comment: okay, so for those cases you can add another RewriteRule to match it. see updated answer. I've also added last rule, which will make default language to `en` if it wasn't given in URL.